# this.$getLocation is not a function is what nuxt is telling me. How do I make it recognize it as one?

Tags: vue.js, geolocation, nuxt.js

```
<script>
export default {
        data() {
            return {
                map: null,
                myCoordinates: {
                    lat: 0,
                    lng: 0
                },
                zoom: 7
            }
        },
        created() {
            // does the user have a saved center? use it instead of the default
            if(process.browser) {
                this.myCoordinates = JSON.parse(localStorage.center);
            } else {
                // get user's coordinates from browser request
                this.$getLocation({})
                    .then(coordinates => {
                        this.myCoordinates = coordinates;
                    })
                    .catch(error => alert(error));
            }
            // does the user have a saved zoom? use it instead of the default
            if(localStorage.zoom) {
                this.zoom = parseInt(localStorage.zoom);
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            // add the map to a data object
            this.$refs.mapRef.$mapPromise.then(map => this.map = map);
        },
        methods: {
            handleDrag() {
                // get center and zoom level, store in localstorage
                let center = {
                    lat: this.map.getCenter().lat(),
                    lng: this.map.getCenter().lng()
                };
                let zoom = this.map.getZoom();
                localStorage.center = JSON.stringify(center);
                localStorage.zoom = zoom;
            }
        },
        computed: {
            mapCoordinates() {
                if(!this.map) {
                    return {
                        lat: 0,
                        lng: 0
                    };
                }
                return {
                    lat: this.map.getCenter().lat().toFixed(4),
                    lng: this.map.getCenter().lng().toFixed(4)
                }
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Every time I run npm run dev, Nuxt tells me that this.$getLocation is not a functionl. This code worked perfectly fine in Vue-cli, but now I can't get it to render a map in Nuxt which I switched to for easier MPA use. How do I get it to recognize that it is a function? Is there an error I'm missing in the code? I followed a tutorial to make it to begin with and only altered it slightly, but the code that was working fine in another Vue project won't transfer over to Nuxt now.

Comment: Does your code require some kind of plugin? That function needs to be defined somewhere. Maybe link the tutorial you followed.

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, I did put in the vue2 Google maps plugin, but not the geolocation one. That could be why. I'll adjust and see if that fixes it.

Comment: This created a new problem "Map: Expected mapDiv of type Element but was passed undefined." I'm not sure what it wants, I have a map div.

Comment: You can't use vue plugins out of the box with nuxt. Take a look at the docs (https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins#vue-plugins), or search for other guides.

Most vue plugins already have a seperate nuxt version if you search for it, so you don't have to do it yourself. This for example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-gmaps

Comment: I'll take a look at that, thank you!